# добавление кириллицы в jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Для создания pdf документа использую jsPDF который принимает либо html строку либо выбранный контейнер, но если в выбранном html есть кириллица, то всё ломается. Пробовал импортировать шрифты как показывается [здесь](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2968), но всё безрезультатно, разве что встроенными методами текст писать а не html строкой. При использовании html2convas дела лучше, но вся кириллица сыпется

```js
export const createPdfFromHtml = (fileName, stringHtml, orientation) => {
  const divContainer = document.createElement('div')
  divContainer.id = "pdfContainer";
  divContainer.innerHTML = stringHtml

  document.getElementById('app').appendChild(divContainer)

  const node = document.getElementById("pdfContainer");
  
  const doc = new jsPDF({format: 'a4',orientation});
  doc.html(node,{
        callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Попробуйте добавить шрифт, который поддерживает кириллицу, как вариант DejaVuSans.ttf.
Добавили:

```
doc.addFont('/path/to/DejaVuSans.ttf', 'DejaVuSans', 'normal');
```

Включили:

```
doc.setFont('DejaVuSans');
```

2. Для работы с канвой пробуйте явно задавать кодировку в настройках html2canvas

   encoding: 'utf-8'
3. Ну и как вариант, если библиотека pdfmake не замеченная в таких проблемах